# PGP Service for .NET Allowing Arbitrary Keys

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, gnupg, pgp

I am in need of a PGP service for .NET that will provide the following:

- Encryption/decryption of files provided as byte arrays and/or streams (e.g. writing to hard drive and having the service read it is unacceptable)
- Use of arbitrary keys passed in as byte arrays and/or streams
- Needs to work for a headless service running on a server with nobody watching it (no modal popups or user input required)

We've felt out a couple of products but not been totally pleased with how any of them worked. Are there any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to guess what you could try as there are not much OpenPGP implementations for .NET. Namely, [OpenPGPBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pgp.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product is the only comprehensive self-contained implementation for .NET (BouncyCastle offers something as well, but they seem to be limited to older RFC 2440). You are welcome to check OpenPGPBlackbox and if you have problems with it, contact our technical support as described on product pages.